# How to fix 'partitions file is not valid and cannot be opened' for SSAS projects in Azure DevOps builds?

Tags: azure-devops, ssas, cube

I'm setting a CI pipeline for deploying SSAS cubes. Running the build script via TFS agent results in "partition is not valid and cannot be open. Check the file". However the same script runs successfully while executing manually on the same server. The script simply calls devenv.com with the path to the solution file. Any ideas what could be the issue?

We have tried the code in both build and rebuild mode, yet the problem persists.

```bsh
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "$(sourcesDirectory)\$(ProjectName).sln" /build development /out "$(sourcesDirectory)\BuildOutputLog.log"
```

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT if that were the case, wouldn't the build fail even when the powershell script is executed manually on the build server?

Comment: I've looked at the build logs generated by both during execution. They don't seem to be conclusive at all. Pretty perplexing

Comment: (confusing why my comment are lost.Sorry did not receive the notification)The only difference between in TFS and local is the User account. For TFS, its a service user account. Not same with the local one.

Comment: true. We have the TFS user account's credentials. We logged in using those and executed the scripts as it would be by TFS. Still the same result.

Comment: What about trying with add the TFS build service account into SQL server and assign it role? I assume this mostly caused by the account permission limit.

Comment: Do we need a SQL server instance on the build server for this to work? We have just installed SSMS, Visual Studio, and "Microsoft Analysis Services Projects" extension

Comment: Yes, the TFS client can access the data in the database need connect with an instance firstly.